# Replace default perl on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: perl, ubuntu

I got a huge project written on Perl, which contains many of scripts which starts with typical #!/usr/bin/perl

For this project I need a custom-built Perl to be compiled from source.

I tried just to replace /usr/bin/perl with my compiled one but OS becomes broken (for ex. module version mismatch etc).

So is there any correct way to replace system perl with my own-built one or the easiest way would be to edit all tons of scripts and replace /usr/bin/perl with /usr/local/bin/perl or something like this?

Comment: Replacing the system Perl can lead to all kinds of trouble. It would make more sense to change all your scripts' shebangs to `#!/usr/bin/env perl` and then compile your own Perl. If you then move that Perl to the front of your PATH for the user that's running the application you should be good.

Comment: In [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454), I discuss the pros and cons of the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to comments, there is no solution to replace system Perl without of destroying something but the're 3 solutions to solve the descibed problem. For all of them i need to modify all the scripts.

1. Using #!/usr/bin/env perl (need to be very careful and place custom perl bin path before all at $PATH of user which runs the script. The nice solution would be to set PATH exactly at crontab.
2. Using straight new perl path at shebang like as #!/usr/local/bin/perl5.26.1
3. Totally remove shebang from scripts and use plain calls at cron and manual runs - like as /usr/bin/perl script.pl. Or just use plain calls - shebang would be ignored.

Special thanks to @Joshua and @ikegami

Comment: In [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454), I discuss the pros and cons of the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick.

Answer (score 5):

Do not replace system perl (or system binaries in general). You can build it to another location (as you suggested, `/usr/local` for example) and call it manually.

My personal preference is to use [plenv](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv). There's a nice guide [here](http://www.dagolden.com/index.php/2390/setting-up-a-perl-development-environment-with-plenv/) to get you started.

If you admin the server and other users are logging in an using your scripts, you'll want to build plenv somewhere outside your home directory (eg. `/opt/plenv`) and ensure that all users $PATH is prepended with the bin path of your new perl. Without digressing too much, this can be done in `/etc/profile` or even better to declare you custom profile mods in a custom profile script (eg. `/etc/profile.d/custom.sh`).

<strike>I would also suggest using a more portable shebang such as `#!/usr/bin/env perl` which will use whichever perl is in a users `$PATH` first. The only exception to this is cron jobs, which I typically always hardcode full paths.</strike> (This is a personal preference based entirely how I admin my boxes and probably not a good idea to recommend unless you know the full repercussions. Administering a server is entirely subjective based on it's use-case, your use-case likely differs vastly from mine).

Comment: Re "*I would also suggest using a more portable shebang*", Please don't!  `#!/usr/bin/env perl` is bad! It's *less* portable because it breaks based on happens to be in the given user's PATH at a given moment! Before installation, the shebang should be `#!/usr/bin/perl`, and after installation, the shebang line should point to the `perl` that installed the module. (This is done automatically by the ExtUtils::MakeMaker and Module::Build.)

Comment: The information I provided is probably not best crammed into a SO reply. You're right that hardcoding is typically more reliable. In the case of plenv, that might be something like `/opt/plenv/shims/perl`. For me, I like to be able to copy my perl scripts between my different servers without having to modify anything. On my various systems, the perl in use might be in 1 of 4 places. I make sure PATH is prepended in `profile` is the `env perl` works for me. YMMV

Comment: It seems that #!/usr/bin/env perl is the only way to solve the issue. Looking forward for a huge amount of job with editing cronjob-scripts and workers:) Thank you!

Comment: Re "*On my various systems, the perl in use might be in 1 of 4 places.*", that assumes there's only one Perl is use, but we're in exactly the opposite situation.

Comment: Audrey: No, as I said, don't rely on env in crontab. In fact I've updated my comment to remove that suggestion. Unless you a good understanding of how shell environments are managed, probably best to hardcode your shebang

Comment: Re "*It seems that #!/usr/bin/env perl is the only way to solve the issue.*", No, *changing your shebang lines*  is the only way to solve the issue. But that's easy to do. It's a simple one liner. `find ... -exec perl -i~ -pe's{^#!/usr/bin/perl}{#!...}' {} +`

Comment: ikegami: I understand env is probably not good advice and I've updated my reply accordingly. Re: my perls... some systems (the old unix/solaris ones) have it in `/usr/bin`, the linux ones have it there too, but on those systems I also have plenv, but in one of two locations. On my local dev system plenv is in home... and possibly on my mac is somewhere else. Syncing changes between systems is less of a hassle for me when I used the env shebang... but I understand that may not best for everyone.

Comment: I think that env is a nice soultion because it would break nothing - as for my project i exactly know the cron-user that should run scripts and it would be easy to set PATH for him. As for manual script starts it also will be easy to control the environment. Why env is bad if the project environment is solid and once-setuped?

Also the env solution is perfect to test project with different perl versions (for example, when we need to update Perl again or to compile a new one with specials) - just one minor editing of env would give a possibility to test stability.

Comment: So just to clarify all. There're 3 solutions. For all of them i need to modify all the scripts.

1. Using #!/usr/bin/env perl
2. Using straight new perl path at shebang
3. Totally remove shebang from scripts and use plain calls at cron and manual runs - like as /usr/bin/perl script.pl

Comment: Audrey, for _any_ users running your scripts in the shell, you would need to make sure '/usr/local/` comes before `/usr/bin` in PATH, or is prepended manually (eg. `PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`). Only then will the env shebang work. You can test by running `perl -v` or `which perl`. If it's just you, you can update PATH in your local `.profile`, otherwise to affect all users it needs to be in the global profile.

Comment: If it's all cron jobs, just hardcode it fully (ie. `0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/perl /full/path/to/script.pl`). This will ignore the shebang. Check your cron logs to ensure things are running successfully.

Comment: Ok, Audrey, but just to be certain! :D You said _"i exactly know the cron-user that should run scripts and it would be easy to set PATH for him."_, but cron does not typically invoke a shell environment (unless you explicitly do so) so PATH may not be what you think. I would always recommend hardcoding paths in crontab.

Comment: There's the way to set PATH exactly at crontab:) (Sorry for formatting)

$ crontab -l
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
*/1 * * * * perl -v > /tmp/perl_version
*/1 * * * * env > /tmp/env

$ cat /tmp/perl_version
This is perl 5, version 26

$ cat /tmp/env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

$ /usr/bin/perl -v
This is perl 5, version 22

Comment: aaaaaand, I've just realised you're name is Andrey, not Audrey. My sincere apologies for that. If I could edit my old comments, I would.